# JQuery 3.x Object doesn't support property or method 'success'

Tags: jquery, yahoo-weather-api

I am using the Yahoo Weather API. It works fine with JQuery 1.x. The issue is with JQuery 3.x. I am getting this error: Object doesn't support property or method 'success'. What can I use instead of .success?

I tried .done based on the documentation but it does not show any data.

https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var city = "Erie, PA";
  var searchtext = "select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='" + city + "') and u='f'"
  $.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + searchtext + "&format=json").success(function(data){
      $('#weather-temp').html(data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp + "°F");
      $("#weather-title").text(data.query.results.channel.title);
      $("#weather-text").text(data.query.results.channel.item.condition.text);
      $("#weather-speed").text("Wind: " + data.query.results.channel.wind.speed + " mph");
      $("#weather-sunset").text("Sunset: " + data.query.results.channel.astronomy.sunset);
      var iconUrl = 'https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?a/i/us/we/52/'
      var weatherCode = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.code;
      $(".weather_icon").attr('src', iconUrl + weatherCode + '.gif');
  });
});
```

Comment: `success` is an ajax option on the properties of the request, not a function on the deferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `getJSON` the success callback can be passed in as the second argument.

Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```js
$.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + searchtext + "&format=json", function(data){
      $('#weather-temp').html(data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp + "°F");
      $("#weather-title").text(data.query.results.channel.title);
      $("#weather-text").text(data.query.results.channel.item.condition.text);
      $("#weather-speed").text("Wind: " + data.query.results.channel.wind.speed + " mph");
      $("#weather-sunset").text("Sunset: " + data.query.results.channel.astronomy.sunset);
      var iconUrl = 'https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?a/i/us/we/52/'
      var weatherCode = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.code;
      $(".weather_icon").attr('src', iconUrl + weatherCode + '.gif');
  });
```

Comment: This means that the callback shall be fired in case the request failed also so validation has to be done in the callback.

Comment: That's not the case at all. The callback is only fired here when the request is successful

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so what if i need to fire some logic in case of failure, i should handle the promise?

Comment: Call `fail()` on the deferred object returned from `$.getJSON()` https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to attach additional logic for the failure case

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
.done(function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Ok, now the link is not relevant to your updated example. I think you meant https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes you are correct. I made a few windows open and copied the wrong link.